# How can I read text per line at Python and convert then to ASCII decimals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ord

What I have tried to do:

```py
f = open('j:/text.txt', 'r')
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
print (''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in line))
print (line)
print (lines)
```

But this converts only the last line and ignores the previous ones.

Comment: well .. put the print _inside_ the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
with open('j:/text.txt', 'r', encoding="ascii") as file :
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    print(''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in line))
```

Comment: work , but i forgot about remove \n at lines

Comment: @tseries, I modified the code to delete the \n. Please mark my answer as the best answer to your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to print every line's ASCII equivelant and the line itself. Put the first two `print` statements inside the `for` loop (Indent them once).

```py
f = open('j:/text.txt', 'r')
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
    print (''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in line))
    print (line)
print (lines)
```

Comment: I should add that the file must be closed too, so it would be better if you used a with statement

Comment: Yeah, but it's best to reproduce the OP's original code.

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen, but it's an *error* in OP's code, and as such, would be more helpful if corrected.